# Draw button on top of AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I have to draw a label or button on top of video `relay next previous , leave comment` . List of video have it, once user select one item from the table,it need to play, Once player play finished, those buttons or label should come on top of video

Here is my code :

```
comPlayerControl = AVPlayerViewController()

if let player = comPlayerControl {

    let videoURL: String = "http://cdnapi.kaltura.com/p/11/sp/11/playManifest/entryId/"+selectedSubmission.transcodeRefId+"/format/applehttp/protocol/http/a.m3u8"
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: NSURL(string: videoURL)! )
    commmentPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    player.player = commmentPlayer
    player.view.frame = videoCell.frame
    player.view.sizeToFit()

    player.showsPlaybackControls = true
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
        self, 
        selector: #selector(CommentsTableViewController.playerDidFinishPlaying(_:)),
        name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, 
        object: playerItem
    )

    comPlayerControl.delegate = self
    videoCell.addSubview(player.view)
}

func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification) {
    print("Video Finished")
    let DynamicView=UIView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 200, 100, 100))
    DynamicView.backgroundColor=UIColor.greenColor()
    DynamicView.layer.cornerRadius=25
    DynamicView.layer.borderWidth=2
    DynamicView.layer.zPosition = 1;
    comPlayerControl.view.addSubview(DynamicView)
}
```

requirement like this

[image: requirement image]

Comment: You can do it easily from the project which was here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36389738/1151916 Only you need add custom buttons and labels in xib file and they will be presented to the user. Which functionality do you want to have?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're using an `AVPlayerViewController`, so there's no reason to access your application's window like in Alessandro Ornano's answer.  Why reinvent the wheel?  Every `AVPlayerViewController` has a [`contentOverlayView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVPlayerViewController/contentOverlayView) property which allows you to place views between the player and the controls.

First, create a new `AVPlayerItem` and listen for the `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification` notification on that item.  Load the item into your player and begin playback.

Once the item completes, the selector your specified to listen for the `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification` notification will be called.  In that selector, access the `contentOverlayView` directly and add your buttons:

In some view controller or other object:

```
let playerVC = AVPlayerViewController()

// ...

func setupPlayer {

    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(...)
    playerVC.player?.replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem(playerItem)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(VC.itemFinished), name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: playerItem)
    self.presentViewController(playerVC, animated: true) { 
        self.playerVC.player?.play()
    }
}

func itemFinished() {
    let btn = UIButton(type: .System)
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(VC.buttonTapped), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    self.playerVC.contentOverlayView?.addSubview(btn)
}

func buttonTapped() {
    print("button was tapped")
    // replay/comment logic here
}
```

As stated in the comments (and a [rejected edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13590865)), buttons may not work in the `contentOverlayView`.  For an alternate solution, see [Pyro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36412673/2415822).

You could also subclass `AVPlayerViewController` and do everything inside an instance of your subclass, but Apple [warns against that](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerViewController_Class/):

> Do not subclass `AVPlayerViewController`. Overriding this class’s methods is unsupported and results in undefined behavior.

Comment: Does this actually work? I can add a view or a button to the content view, but for some reason I do not seem to get  the button to receive touches... I've tried with iOS 10 and 11.

Comment: i dont use avplayerviewcontroller. how to achive the same only with player or playerLayer?

Answer (score 4):

I think the best way to make the avplayer buttons is explained here: [IOS 8 Video Playback using AVPlayer and AVPlayerViewController](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_8_Video_Playback_using_AVPlayer_and_AVPlayerViewController) .

So , I prefeer and agree with these instructions, but if you still want to 
add these buttons you can try to add them to the self.window

```
if let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate, let window = app.window {
        let myFirstButton = UIButton()
        myFirstButton.setTitle("test", forState: .Normal)
        window.addSubview(myFirstButton)
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I recommend looking up AVPlayerLayer as a way to show buttons and other content on top of your video.

See the [Advances in AVFoundation Playback](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/503/) WWDC presentation.

Also, check out the [AVFoundationSimplePlayer-iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/AVFoundationSimplePlayer-iOS/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016103) example project.

Essentially, you create a view to host your player, and you make the layer behind the view into an AVPlayerLayer.

```
class PlayerView: UIView {
    var player: AVPlayer? {
        get {
            return playerLayer.player
        }

        set {
            playerLayer.player = newValue
        }
    }

    var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer {
        return layer as! AVPlayerLayer
    }

    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return AVPlayerLayer.self
    }
}
```

Comment: I found this answer useful.

Comment: how to use this class please help me ?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the your question and from the comment/code of **Ramis** i have made a sample code which you may try

As mentioned by **JAL** the `contentOverlayView` should be the best option to display the control over the video in the `AVPlayerController`, but as per my sample demo the `contentOverlayView` don't have any user interaction for the buttons or other controls, as if you check in the 3D view of the `AVPlayerController` it has `AVTouchIgnoringView`/`UIView` in front of the `contentOverlayView` which may be problem in user interaction with `contentOverlayView`.

So another solution is to add the overlay view in the AVPlayerViewController

```
func addContentOverlayView() {

    OverlayView.frame = CGRectMake(0,30,AVPlayerVC.view.bounds.width, 100)
    OverlayView.hidden = true
    OverlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor ( red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0.379 )

    let btnNext = UIButton(frame:CGRectMake(AVPlayerVC.view.bounds.width - 60,0,60,44))
    btnNext.setTitle(">>", forState:.Normal)
    btnNext.addTarget(self, action:"playNext", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
    //        btnNext.layer.borderColor = UIColor ( red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 0.670476140202703 ).CGColor
    //        btnNext.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    OverlayView.addSubview(btnNext)

    let btnReplay = UIButton(frame:CGRectMake((AVPlayerVC.view.bounds.width/2)-40,0,80,44))
    btnReplay.setTitle("Replay", forState:.Normal)
    btnReplay.addTarget(self, action:"replayVideo", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
    OverlayView.addSubview(btnReplay)

    let btnPrevious = UIButton(frame:CGRectMake(0,0,80,44))
    btnPrevious.setTitle("<<", forState:.Normal)
    btnPrevious.addTarget(self, action:"previousVideo", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
    OverlayView.addSubview(btnPrevious)

    let btnComment = UIButton(frame:CGRectMake((AVPlayerVC.view.bounds.width/2)-70,40,140,44))
    btnComment.setTitle("Comments", forState:.Normal)
    btnComment.addTarget(self, action:"openComments", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
    OverlayView.addSubview(btnComment)

    AVPlayerVC.view.addSubview(OverlayView);

}

func playNext() {
    prevItem = AVPlayerVC.player?.currentItem
    OverlayView.hidden = true
    commmentQueuePlayer.advanceToNextItem()
}

func replayVideo() {
    OverlayView.hidden = true
    AVPlayerVC.player?.currentItem?.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)
    AVPlayerVC.player?.play()
}

func previousVideo() {
    OverlayView.hidden = true
    if prevItem != AVPlayerVC.player?.currentItem {
        if (commmentQueuePlayer.canInsertItem(prevItem!, afterItem:AVPlayerVC.player?.currentItem)) {
            //commmentQueuePlayer.insertItem(prevItem!, afterItem:AVPlayerVC.player?.currentItem)
            commmentQueuePlayer.replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem(prevItem)
            prevItem = AVPlayerVC.player?.currentItem
            replayVideo()
        }
    } else {
        replayVideo()
        //Else display alert no prev video found
    }
}

func stopedPlaying() {
    if prevItem == nil {
        prevItem = AVPlayerVC.player?.currentItem
    }
    OverlayView.hidden = false
}
```

At the initial setup we set the AVPlayerController,AVQueuePlayer etc... at that time we can add the overlay on the AVPlayerController

For the previous item there is no direct available and as per documentation the item will be remove once it's next item is played , so we have two option like `replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem` or `insertItem(item: AVPlayerItem, afterItem: AVPlayerItem?)`

If you need to check complete code you can check it from :
https://gist.github.com/Pyrolr/debb4fca8f608b1300e099a5b3547031

**Note:** This is just like prototype, it is not working perfectly in all the cases but it can help you in understanding the basic functionality you wnat and you can improve/optimise based on your requirements

Answer (score 0):

Check Below code, I am able to add the button on overlay as well as button event is being called.

```
var playerViewController: AVPlayerViewController?
var OverlayView = UIView()    
    
private lazy var button1: UIButton = {
                    let selfType = type(of: self)
                    let button = UIButton(frame: .init(origin: .zero, size: .init(width: selfType.musicWidth, height: selfType.musicHeight)))
                    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "star"), for: .normal)
                    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(button1DidSelect), for: .touchUpInside)
                    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: selfType.musicWidth),
                        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: selfType.musicHeight)
                    ])
                    return button
                }()
        
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
                    super.viewDidAppear(true)
                    guard let url = URL(string: "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4") else { return  }
                    let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
                    self.playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
                    guard let playerViewController = self.playerViewController else { return }
                    playerViewController.player = player
                    
                    present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
                        playerViewController.player?.play()
                    }
                
                        self.addButtonsOnOverlayView()
                        self.playerViewController?.showsPlaybackControls = false
                        self.isHideOverlayControls = false
                }
    
     
    
@objc private func button1DidSelect() {
                print("button1 Selected")
                
            }
    
 private func addButtonsOnOverlayView() {
            
            guard let overlayView = self.playerViewController?.contentOverlayView else { return }
            
            if !self. button1.isDescendant(of: overlayView) {
                overlayView.addSubview(self.musicFirstButton)
                 self.playerViewController?.showsPlaybackControls = true
    
            }
            
               NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                button1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: overlayView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
                button1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: overlayView.topAnchor, constant: 20),
            ])
          
        }
```